# ImportError : No module named graphics

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, graphics, pip

I tried working on a graphics algorthims which requires a graphics package so i imported graphics the code is here

```
from graphics import *
import time

def BresenhamLine(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    """ Bresenham Line Drawing Algorithm For All Kind Of Slopes Of Line """

    dx = abs(x2 - x1)
    dy = abs(y2 - y1)
    slope = dy/float(dx)

    x, y = x1, y1   

    # creating the window
    win = GraphWin('Brasenham Line', 600, 480)

    # checking the slope if slope > 1 
    # then interchange the role of x and y
    if slope > 1:
        dx, dy = dy, dx
        x, y = y, x
        x1, y1 = y1, x1
        x2, y2 = y2, x2

    # initialization of the inital disision parameter
    p = 2 * dy - dx

    PutPixle(win, x, y)

    for k in range(2, dx):
        if p > 0:
            y = y + 1 if y < y2 else y - 1
            p = p + 2*(dy - dx)
        else:
            p = p + 2*dy

        x = x + 1 if x < x2 else x - 1

        # delay for 0.01 secs
        time.sleep(0.01)
        PutPixle(win, x, y)

def PutPixle(win, x, y):
    """ Plot A Pixle In The Windows At Point (x, y) """
    pt = Point(x,y)
    pt.draw(win)

def main():
    x1 = int(input("Enter Start X: "))
    y1 = int(input("Enter Start Y: "))
    x2 = int(input("Enter End X: "))
    y2 = int(input("Enter End Y: "))

    BresenhamLine(x1, y1, x2, y2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when i executed this code which gave me this error

```
python app.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from graphics import *
ImportError: No module named graphics
```

So i tried to install graphics package from pip but i too failed.

```
sudo pip install graphics
Downloading/unpacking graphics
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement graphics
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for graphics
Storing debug log for failure in /home/ubuntu/.pip/pip.log
```

How to rectify this error?

Comment: Ask whoever wrote the documentation that you're working from where it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to download [this file](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py) and put it in the same folder with your script.

From the docstring:

> INSTALLATION: Put this file somewhere where Python can see it.

Answer (score -2):

click to the link shown here.
https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics.py
Now follow this : select all text data > copy > save (in working folder) > graphics.py > enter. Create a new file like <test.py> , write code and test it.

Comment: This is the same solution as in [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40200079/2227743). *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*